# Can't access the index of my array in async-await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, redux-toolkit

why every time I try to access the index of my array it returns undefined? Also, I've tried to check it using type of it also returns object instead of array.

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { firestore } from 'firebase/firebaseConfig';

const RETRIEVE_COMMENTS = createAsyncThunk('retrieveComments', async ({ docID }) => {
    try {
        let retrievedComments = []
        const comments = await firestore
            .collection('products')
            .doc(docID)
            .collection('comments')
            .orderBy("timestamp")

        comments.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach((res) => retrievedComments.push(res.data()))
        })
        console.log(retrievedComments[0])
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})

export default RETRIEVE_COMMENTS
```

Comment: Hi @Nisala, thanks for the reply but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are you trying to just fetch the data once, or continuously as it updates?

Comment: Continuously updates

Comment: Alright. What's stopping you from just putting your code in the `onSnapshot` function? Like, after you do the `forEach` in there, you should be able to `console.log` with no problem (unless there's no matching data)

Comment: comments.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach((res) => retrievedComments.push(res.data()))
    console.log(retrievedComments[0])
}) something like that

Comment: I've already done that. But what I'm trying to accomplish is to pass the "array" that contains the data to the component in react

Answer (score 0):

#### snapshot -> constantly listens to the collection

---

use the Promise returned from your write operation by attaching a .then()

---

If you want to receive snapshot events when the document or query metadata changes, pass a listen options object when attaching your listener:

```
db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot({
        // Listen for document metadata changes
        includeMetadataChanges: true
    }, (doc) => {
        // ...
    });
```

in your case :

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { firestore } from 'firebase/firebaseConfig';

const RETRIEVE_COMMENTS = createAsyncThunk('retrieveComments', async ({ docID }) => {
    try {
        let retrievedComments = []
        const comments = await firestore
            .collection('products')
            .doc(docID)
            .collection('comments')
            .orderBy("timestamp")

        comments.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach((res) => retrievedComments.push(res.data()))
        }).then(doc => console.log(doc))
        console.log(retrievedComments[0])
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})

export default RETRIEVE_COMMENTS
```

i am sorry if that not what you need I can not comment on your question I do not have more than  50 REPUTATION to comment